# Google People API: Invalid JSON payload received (Postman)

Tags: google-people-api

Working and trying to test the Google People API in postman, and running into the following error.

```
>   "error": {
>     "code": 400,
>     "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"personFields\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'personFields'
> could not be found in request message.",
>     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
>     "details": [
>       {
>         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
>         "fieldViolations": [
>           {
>             "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"personFields\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field
> 'personFields' could not be found in request message."
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     ]   } }
```

Here is the GET request I am trying to run:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchContacts?query=removedEmailForPrivacy@email.com&personFields=person.email_addresses
```

I have read through the google People [Docs](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) but do not quite understand what I am doing wrong. In the docs it mentions I need a personFields query param, yet it is throwing the error above. I assume my formatting is wrong in some sense, but there aren't a ton of concrete examples I could find online.

For more context, I am attempting to search through the user's contact book and try and find the email address, and return pertinent information. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking to do is search through another user's contact book instead you need to use the endpoint below:

> GET [https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}/connections](https://people.googleapis.com/v1/%7BresourceName=people/*%7D/connections)

As [documented here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) this is the one to be used to achieve what you need:

> "... Provides a list of the authenticated user's contacts ..."

Using the above this is the URL you will need in Postman:

> https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageSize=300&personFields=emailAddresses

Where:

Me = the authenticated user.

PageSize = can be any number from 1 to 1000

#### Something to note:

1. If you would like to add other personFields attributes, you can do so by separating them with commas. *Like: personFields=emailAddresses,phoneNumbers*
2. You did not mention whether the other account you want to check is a free Gmail.com account or a Google Workspace one.
3. If the latter is your case. you will need to impersonate the user to be able to access the user's contact list. I tested on my end, but I am not really sure how to go about doing that on Postman. If impersonation is not done you will only be able to use: "me" as the required resourceName parameter.

Comment: This is a good answer. Additionally, I encourage folks to use Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer), e.g. for [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/) and it provides a form (like Postman) to execute methods e.g. [`people.searchContacts`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts). It makes it easier to be successful.